# use implode in $_GET

Tags: php, arrays, post, get

I have some forms in my page like :

```
    <form method="get">
Enter Your Firstname :<input type="text" name="t1"  />
Enter Your Lastname :<input type="text" name="t2"  />
<input type="submit" name="sb" />
</form>
```

so users will fill this form and i want to have values of this form separated with comma

for example

```
John,Smith
James,Baker
```

so here is my php code

```
if ( isset ($_GET['sb']))
{
    $t_array = array("t1","t2");
    foreach ( $t_array as $key ) 
    {
        echo implode(',' , $_GET[$key]);
    }
}
```

When i try to do this , i got this error :

```
Warning: implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in PATH on line 24
```

i don't know why i can't use implode in $_GET or $_POST

so how can i solve this problem ?

P.S : i want to use array and implode in my page , please don't write about other ways

Comment: `$_GET['t1']` is not an array but a string. I guess what you need is an `explode`.

Comment: $_GET[$key] is not an array. It is a string value. You have to pass second parameter as array for implode

Comment: @Hassan so how can i receive my form data as input1,input2 ?

Comment: Viktor Todorov gave you the right answer

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your logic.

here is sample code that might help you:

```
$t_array = array($_GET['t1'], $_GET['t2']);
$imploded = implode(',', $t_array);
echo $imploded;
```

This will work.

Comment: Why not do it in one line? `$_GET['t1'].','.$_GET['t2']`. Or is it a new game where everything has to be done with `implode`? :)

Comment: Thank you for the notice. The idea was to explain the way of using implode.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling implode on a value, not an array. This code

```
echo implode(',' , $_GET[$key]);
```

calls it on `$_GET[$key]`, which is a string.

You are trying for `implode($_GET);`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like below, you don't actually need implode for this:

```
if ( isset ($_GET['sb']))
{
    $t_array = array("t1","t2");
    $result = '';
    foreach ( $t_array as $key ) 
    {
        if ($result != '') $result .= ',';
        $result .= $_GET[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: please read my post again ...
i want to save this values in database , so i need to receive them via GET or POST !
i want to separated each of forms value with comma

Answer (score 0):

You can't impode strings...

Try something like this:

```
if ( isset ($_GET['sb']))
{
    $t_array = array("t1","t2");
    $arr = array();
    foreach ( $t_array as $key ) 
    {
        $arr[] = $_GET[$key];
    }
    echo implode(',' , $arr);
}
```